# PyTorch methods that can only be called from `forward`

Tags: pytorch, autograd

In the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html) for extending `torch.autograd`:

> ...please refer to the docs of [Function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function) to find descriptions of
> useful methods that can be called only from `forward()`.

But following that link, it's not clear to me what they're referring to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are referring to the methods only accessible in the forward method. In the scope of the `forward` method, `self` is conventionally named `ctx` and is provided as an [object mixin](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#context-method-mixins). There are *four* special functions available on that mixin: [`mark_dirty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.function.FunctionCtx.mark_dirty.html), [`mark_non_differentiable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.function.FunctionCtx.mark_non_differentiable.html), [`save_for_backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.function.FunctionCtx.save_for_backward.html), and [`set_materialize_grads`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.function.FunctionCtx.set_materialize_grads.html).